# Loading data with Task still hangs UI

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a WPF form with several tabs on in. When I load the form I am also trying to load some data in the background for some of the tabs.

The code looks like this:

```
public static List<MyModel> GetCaseNotes(int someId)
{
   return GetCaseNotesAsync(debtorId).Result;
}

public static async Task<List<MyModel>> GetCaseNotesAsync(int someId)
{
     Task<List<MyModel>> tsk = Task.Run(() => GetCaseNotesFromDb(someId));


     return await tsk.ConfigureAwait(false);

}

public static List<MyModel> GetCaseNotesFromDb(int debtorId)
{

   //get some data from database
}
```

However, the UI is still waiting for the data to be taken from database... Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Result` will block until the task completes. You've avoided the [deadlock I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by using `ConfigureAwait`, but you're still explicitly blocking.

When loading data asynchronously, you'll need to design in a "loading" state for your UI and update it when the loading completes. I have another blog entry on [asynchronous construction/initialization](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) that you may find useful, in particular my [`NotifyTaskCompletion` type](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyTaskCompletion) attempts to make tasks more data-binding-friendly.

Comment: Great post on the blog! I'm new to this and it's useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
return GetCaseNotesAsync(debtorId).Result;
```

should be

```
return await GetCaseNotesAsync(debtorId);
```

When you call `Result` on a `Task`, you wait synchronously for the result, not asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have async method but calling it synchronously. **Calling Async method without await will cause it to behave as a synchronous method**.

In order to call it  asynchronously you should call it like this

```
 return await GetCaseNotesAsync(debtorId);
```

Comment: If you're using `await` you don't want `.Result` on the end